# Searching .init section in ELF file

Tags: linux, elf, string-table

How can I find section `.init`? 
Section header has field `Elf32_Word sh_name`. So I suppose I have to go through all sections to find one with name `.init` But `sh_name` is not an array of chars. It is an index of entry in String Table. 
Where is String Table? There is field `elfHdr.e_shstrndx` in the ELF header. It is index of section there String Table is situated. 
So to calculate offset of String Table I use formula which is described below.

```
offset = ((elfHdr.e_shstrndx)*elfHdr.e_shentsize)+elfHdr.e_shoff,  
where 
elfHdr.e_shstrndx = index where we can find .shstrtab
elfHdr.e_shentsize = Size of each Section Header
elfHdr.e_shoff = Offset at which section header starts.
```

But the turned-out offset is not correct offset of String Table. I have tried it on various files.
May be there is another way to determine whether section is `.init` or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you almost got it right.

The `offset` you've calculated is a file offset in bytes of the section header of the String Table section. Again, this is the beginning of this section's header and it will be a structure of type `Elf32_Shdr`. Now you should read its `sh_offset` and *this* will be the offset to the list of strings you are looking for.